# How to find PHPMyAdmin database details

Tags: php, mysql, web

```
$myhost = "";
$myuser = "";
$mypass = "";
$mydb = "";
```

Where in the PhpMyAdmin panel would I find these details? I can't find them on my hosting panel! (I use MediaTemple Grid Hosting)

I have the username and password but don't know what to put for myhost and mydb!

My PHPMyAdmin Username to login looks like this: db111111_test

But with different numbers after db.

Would db111111 be the db or would _test or test be the db? Also what would the host be?

Comment: You won't find all details in PHPMyAdmin. Espescially not password. Btw: flagging as off topic cause it has not really something to do with programming.

Comment: What would myhost and mydb be then? for example if my username was db111111_name

Answer (score 0):

http://(ip-of-server)/phpmyadmin

or you can read this

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643690/managing-a-mysql-database-with-phpmyadmin

Comment: I have the username and password, but don't know what to put for host and mydb

Comment: you have install the phpmyadmin yourself?

Comment: I used my hosting provider (media temple). What do I put for Host and MyDB though?

Comment: You need to login to your "c-panel". login here -> https://ac.mediatemple.net/login.mt . after the login you should go to the pannel where it says: Websites and Domains. I think the best think to do is to send an email to mediatemple and tell them about your problem. The would take care for you!